# What is the quickest way to delete many blobs from GCS?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a bucket containing many millions of blobs that I want to delete however I can't simply delete the bucket. This is the best method I have come up with to delete millions of blobs in the quickest time possible:

```
gsutil ls gs://bucket/path/to/dir/ | xargs gsutil -m rm -r
```

For what I want to do (which involves removing about 30million blobs) it still takes many hours to run, partly I guess because its at the mercy of the speed of my broadband connection.

Anyone know of a quicker way of achieving this? I had kinda hoped it'd be an instantaneous operation as in the backend the location could simply be marked as deleted - clearly not.

Comment: Unless your broadband connection is very slow (<10mb) that is not your problem. Network latency is part of the problem, the primary problem is that you can only delete one object at a time per REST API. The solution is to delete objects in parallel. There might be a published tool with that feature or you can write your own.

Comment: We’ll I’m using the -m switch which does exactly that, issues many delete operations in parallel. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rm

Comment: I have written code for a commercial product to solve this problem with performance about 100x the CLI. If your system is the bottleneck, launch a VM in the same region as the bucket and run the command there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google recommend using the console to do this

> The Cloud Console can bulk delete up to several million objects and does so in the background. The Cloud Console can also be used to bulk delete only those objects that share a common prefix, which appear as part of a folder when using the Cloud Console.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#deleting

That said (personal opinion here) using the console might be quicker but you haven't a clue how far its got. At least with cli option you do know.

Answer (score 1):

For the cases when prefix in not common, one can use batch method to delete **up to 100** files in a single call.

```
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.storage.blob import Blob
from google.cloud.exceptions import NotFound

bucket_name = "<your.gcs.bucket>"

def delete_batch(lst):
    client = storage.Client(project="project_id", credentials="<credentials")
    bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blobs_to_delete = [Blob(l, bucket) for l in lst]

    try:
        with client.batch():
            for blob in blobs_to_delete:
                blob.delete()
    except NotFound:
        print "some paths were missing"
```

This might not be a fastest way to delete millions of files, but gives flexibility to delete random links from your bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is using lifecycle management to delete based on rules:

> Delete objects in bulk
>
> If you want to bulk delete a hundred thousand or more objects, avoid
> using `gsutil`, as the process takes a long time to complete. Instead,
> use the Google Cloud console, which can delete up to several million
> objects, or Object Lifecycle Management, which can delete any number
> of objects.
>
> To bulk delete objects in your bucket using Object Lifecycle
> Management, set a lifecycle configuration rule on your bucket where
> the condition has `Age` set to `0` days, and the action is set to `delete`.

From: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects#delete-objects-in-bulk

However this won't work if you're in a rush:

> After you have added or edited a rule, it may take up to 24 hours to take effect.